# splitting the layout in Android

Tags: android, layout, android-animation

I am unable to create two layouts at a time on a page in Android- I have one main layouts  after clicking on back button of that layout it should slide 20 % of that page and it display the list of menu options and front page at a time in Android

Answer (score 0):

You can use [animation](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/) for this purpose....when animation completed then hide layout i.e menu will be shown....

Comment: Thanq for ur reply but in that example it is navigating the whole page but i need the menu should be visible and then it should be over lap by the page

Comment: By using animation you also animate half of the page like following example...
`<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:fromYDelta="-20%p" android:toYDelta="0%p"
 android:duration="@string/duration"/>`

Here I am show 20% portion of mobile and after animation complete i show menu which created in LinearLayout on 20% portion...
And for hide
`<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="-20%p"
 android:duration="@string/duration" />`
after animation I hide that Layout...
Hope It's help you